# Custom Calendar with Dot Icon & List

Tags: java, android

I am making a small program in which i want to show List of Events as well as Dot Icon on Event Dates

Whenever i use this line, getting **Dot Icon** but not getting List of Events :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // [dot]
```

And when i use below line, getting **List of Events** but not getting Dot Icon :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); // [List]
```

See my whole code, i have written to develop this program....

**CalendarAdapter.java:**

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    private java.util.Calendar month;
    public GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
    /**
     * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
     */
    public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
    private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
    int firstDay;
    int maxWeeknumber;
    int maxP;
    int calMaxP;
    int lastWeekDay;
    int leftDays;
    int mnthlength;
    String itemvalue,curentDateString;
    DateFormat df;

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    public static List<String> dayString;
    private View previousView;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar) {
        CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        month = monthCalendar;
        selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
        mContext = c;
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
        refreshDays();
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
                items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
            }
        }
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dayString.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dayString.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        TextView dayView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);
        }
        dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        // separates daystring into parts.
        String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
        // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
        String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
        // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
        if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
            // setting offdays to white color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else {
            // setting curent month's days in blue color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
            setSelected(v);
            previousView = v;
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        dayView.setText(gridvalue);

        // create date string for comparison
        String date = dayString.get(position);

        if (date.length() == 1) {
            date = "0" + date;
        }
        String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
            monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
        }

        // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
        ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
        if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
            iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return v;
    }

    public View setSelected(View view) {
        if (previousView != null) {
            previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        previousView = view;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshDays() {
        // clear items
        items.clear();
        dayString.clear();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
        // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
        firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        // finding number of weeks in current month.
        maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
        mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
        maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
        calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
        /**
         * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
         * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
         */
        pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
        /**
         * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
         */
        pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

        /**
         * filling calendar gridview.
         */
        for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

            itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
            pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            dayString.add(itemvalue);
        }
    }

    private int getMaxP() {
        int maxP;
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }
        maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return maxP;
    }

}
```

**CalendarView.java:**

```
public class CalendarView extends Activity {

    public GregorianCalendar month, itemmonth;// calendar instances.

    public CalendarAdapter adapter;// adapter instance
    public Handler handler;// for grabbing some event values for showing the dot
                            // marker.
    public ArrayList<String> items; // container to store calendar items which
                                    // needs showing the event marker
    public static ArrayList<String> event;
    LinearLayout rLayout;
    ArrayList<String> date;
    ArrayList<String> desc;
    ArrayList<Integer> image;
    ListView listview;
    ListAdapter _listadapter;
    String[] months = {"January", "February",
              "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
              "August", "September", "October", "November",
              "December"};

    String selectedYear;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

        rLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.text);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
        month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        itemmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();

        items = new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, month);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater);

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
        selectedYear = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy", month).toString();
        RelativeLayout previous = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.previous);

        previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
        });

        RelativeLayout next = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
        });

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                // removing the previous view if added
                if (((LinearLayout) rLayout).getChildCount() > 0) {
                    ((LinearLayout) rLayout).removeAllViews();
                }
                desc = new ArrayList<String>();
                date = new ArrayList<String>();
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
                String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                        .get(position);
                String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
                String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                        "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
                int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
                // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
                if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                    setPreviousMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                    setNextMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                }
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

                for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                    if (Utility.startDates.get(i).equals(selectedGridDate)) {
                        desc.add(Utility.nameOfEvent.get(i));
                    }
                }

                if (desc.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < desc.size(); i++) {
                        TextView rowTextView = new TextView(CalendarView.this);

                        rowTextView
                                .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, // LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                        1));

                        rowTextView.setText("Event:" + desc.get(i));
                        rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                        rLayout.addView(rowTextView);
                    }
                }
                desc = null;
            }
        });
    }

    protected void setNextMonth() {
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + 1),
                    month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        }
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    protected void setPreviousMonth() {
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    protected void showToast(String string) {
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void refreshCalendar() {
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        adapter.refreshDays();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater); // generate some calendar items

        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
        selectedYear = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy", month).toString();
    }

    public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            items.clear();

            // Print dates of the current week
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US);
            String itemvalue;
            event = Utility.readCalendarEvent_static(CalendarView.this);
            Log.d("=====Event====", event.toString());
            Log.d("=====Date ARRAY====", Utility.image.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                itemvalue = df.format(itemmonth.getTime());
                itemmonth.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
                items.add(Utility.startDates.get(i).toString());
            }
            adapter.setItems(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            goToList(listview);
        }
    };

    public void goToList(View v) {
        desc = new ArrayList<String>();
        date = new ArrayList<String>();
        image = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        String month = months[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
        System.out.println("Month name: " + month);
        for(int i=0;i< Utility.startDates.size();i++) {  
        String [] yearString = Utility.startDates.get(i).split(" ");   
        String [] currentCalanderYear = selectedYear.split(" ");
            if(currentCalanderYear[0].equalsIgnoreCase(yearString[0])) {
                desc.add(CalendarView.event.get(i));
                date.add(Utility.startDates.get(i));
                image.add(Utility.image.get(i));
            }
        }

        if(desc.size()>0) {
        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _listadapter = new ListAdapter(CalendarView.this);
        listview.setAdapter(_listadapter);
        } else {
            listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }       
    }

    private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        public ListAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return desc.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_row, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
                viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txteventname);
                viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txteventdate);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.logo.setBackgroundResource(image.get(position));
            viewHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc
                        .get(position)));
            viewHolder.date.setText(Html.fromHtml(date
                        .get(position)));

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView date;
        ImageView logo;
    }
}
```

Comment: why it has been down voted?

Comment: what's wrong here, i just want to know how can i show dot icon and list together in my program

Comment: @G_S still facing same issue, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Let me try now... Actually was busy on other thing and i didnt try running your code. Let me try now

Comment: @G_S sure please try it once, I hope you will find some solution

Comment: would you mind to post the layout files too so that my task becomes a bit easy instead of doing it from the scratch

Comment: sure i will place xmls as well, just wait

Comment: @G_S i placed all xmls as well, check now, i think it will help you

Comment: Ok let me take a look and will get to u back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is

In calenderAdapter class : The list "**items**" has date in format something like  "**November 03, 2013**" and the dayString with which you are comparing is in the format of something like "**2013-10-27**".

So the if condition

```
if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(daystring)) {
            iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

is **false** and you are not able to set visibility of the image to **visible**.

Try converting daystring to format like "**November 03, 2013**" and your problem gets solved.

You can try something like this :

```
 String value = String.format("%s %s, %s",getMonthForInt(separatedTime[1]),separatedTime[2],separatedTime[0]);
```

and the method is defined as below

```
String getMonthForInt(String monthNum) 
{
        String month = "";
        DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
        int m = Integer.parseInt(monthNum) - 1;
        String[] months = dfs.getMonths();
        if (m >= 0 && m <= 11 ) {
            month = months[m];
        }
        return month;
}
```

And change your if condition to

```
  if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(value)) {
        iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Hope this helps you. Happy coding.

Comment: Happy to hear. It helped you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

In this code, your date format is different in Calendar adapter and your listview,
So replace line in Calendar adapter from
df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
to 
df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US);

Comment: yeah i already tried but getting: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException    see my updated question

Comment: Format this line dayString.get(position).split("-") as per your date format or use "yyyy-MM-dd" date format in your listview

Comment: tried not resolved, can i send you my code, try at your end, if yes so  mention your email id here or send me an email at sonali.kohlimca@gmail.com –